# iOS: How to run web service without open application after installed in iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to run web service without open `application`

- I need to run an service without open the app.
- Once app closed from `background` also it must be run service.
- Its an `security` app like `anti theft` functionality.

Can anybody help to run service `without open app` ?

Comment: Have you had a look into background fetch? iOS will periodically open you app to call a webservice. Unsure whether it works whilst you app is terminated though.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can not, from a browser, check if an app is installed or not.

But you can try redirecting the phone to the app, and if nothing happens redirect the phone to a specified page, like this:

```
    setTimeout(function (){
    window.location = "https://itunes.apple.com/appdir"; 
    }, 25);
    window.location = "appname://";
```

If the second line of code gives a result then the first row is never executed.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can check the "Implementing long-running background tasks" section  from [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html) document.

or

You can use by local notification to do that. But this not check every time. You set the time to where you will check a particular event.
Here is the tutorial for [creating Local Notification](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/07/29/iphone-programming-tutorial-local-notifications/) step by step.